# setAdapter method from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I need to run this line not from my main activity but from onPostExecute method of AsyncTask.

```
listView.setAdapter (new MyAdapter(this));
```

listView is a ListVIew which I have declared in my main activity.

the reason I want to do it is because I want the AsynchTask to finish its doInbackground mathod before calling setAdapter.

the problem is that I can't write that line as it is (with "this) ..what argument can I write instead of "this"?

or is there any way to check if doInBackground has finished from the main activity?

Comment: pass Activity context instead of `this`

Comment: can you please be more spesific ? where do I declare the the activity context? ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are unable to write 'this' inside the AsyncTask is because you are within the context of AsyncTask at that time and you cannot use the context of that as it is not valid.

To fix this, you could use the context of the activity that you obtain elsewhere in the code. You could do something like:

```
Context ctxt = this;
```

Within onPostExecute(), you can set your list adapter with the context ctxt.

Comment: so ctxt should be declared in my main Activity..right?

Comment: Yes.. you should declare it in the activity where your AsyncTask resides in

Comment: You can also use the Activity context by ActivityName.this where ActivityName is the name of your current activity class.

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
listView.setAdapter (new MyAdapter(MyActivity.this));
```